# Set max and min date for primefaces schedule

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

How can I set the date range for p:schedule?
I have tried using the extender attribute like following

```
<p:schedule extender="scheduler" value="#{scheduleView.eventModel}" view="#{scheduleView.view}" rightHeaderTemplate="agendaWeek, agendaDay">
...
</p:schedule>
<h:outputScript>

    function scheduler() {
        this.cfg = $.extend(true, this.cfg, {
            validRange : {
                start: '2018-05-06',
                end: '2018-05-26'
            }
        });

    }

</h:outputScript>
```

Using primefaces v6.2.
What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: is the scheduler () function called?

Comment: Yeah... it's getting invoked.

Comment: did you try setting validRange by not using `$.extend`?

Comment: @Kukeltje 
Yeah... I tried like
`this.cfg.validRange = {
    start: '2018-05-06',
    end: '2018-05-26'
};`

Comment: and it did not work?.

Comment: It's not working

Comment: according to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange you have to add it to a view

Comment: Sorry I think I misinterpreted.